# JobRunr: Deleting and Recreating the schedule with same schedule Id & different time never runs

Tags: java, spring-boot, jobrunr

I am using JobRunr 5.0.1 with Spring Boot Parent version 3.6.7. I have an edit endpoint where I am deleting the schedule by Id and creating the new one with the same Id but updated time details. The schedule don't runs at the updated scheduled time although the JobRunr Dashboard shows the updated schedule Time and all the other details too.
Did anybody know whether its a known issue/bug or am I missing something ?

Note (Not Sure): Previously I was using JobRunr 4..10 and spring boot version 3.6.6 and seems it was working But now not working even with the older said versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed with JobRunr 5.1.3.